# Add similar behavior to a group of WinForms controls

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a form with 6 buttons. These buttons serve to increase/decrease tha value of the respective textbox. Now I'm trying to "animate" the buttons. I want to get another effect on the button when the mouse is over him.

[image: My form]

To do that, I have two diferent images in Resources and I am doing this code:

```
private void btnHoursDown_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    btnHoursDown.Image = Game_Helper.Properties.Resources.DownHover;
}

private void btnHoursDown_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    btnHoursDown.Image = Game_Helper.Properties.Resources.Down;
}
```

This works fine. My question is: it wouldn't be wise to create a class (ButtonBehaviour.cs) and put this code in that class?

So I would have something like this:

```
ButtonBehaviour buttonBehaviour = new ButtonBehaviour();
private void btnHoursDown_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    buttonBehaviour.buttonDownHover();
}

private void btnHoursDown_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    buttonBehaviour.buttonDownLeave();
}
```

And the class should be:

```
public class ButtonBehaviour {
    public void buttonDownHover() {
       // code
    }

    public void buttonDownLeave() {
       // code
    }
}
```

How can I create this Class Behaviour and make the buttons adapt this Behaviour?

Comment: you want inheritance probably

Comment: I'll join those two Thomases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if one effect should be applied for all buttons, try to add the same event handlers to them

```
private void btn_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Image = Game_Helper.Properties.Resources.DownHover;
}

private void btn_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Image = Game_Helper.Properties.Resources.Down;
}
```

button which raised event is available via `sender` variable

this way you avoid code duplication for every button. creating a `ButtonBehaviour` or `CustomButton` is probably an over-engineering unless you need them in many forms

Comment: I'm learning c# and starting to work with classes, so I did this little project to get more confortable working with classes. This code that you posted, is the class ButtonBehaviour code?
Edit: Just tested this code in my Form, seems to work, but this way, I don't need the class Behaviour right?

Comment: @F.Carvalho, no, it is code in `form` in place of `btnHoursDown_MouseHover`,`btnHoursDown_MouseHover`; do you have similar methods for `btnMinutesDown`, `btnSecondsDown`? for 3 of them you can re-use methods `btn_MouseHover`,`btn_MouseLeave`

Comment: Yes, I do. So I should be using this code for the 3 Decreasing buttons (Hours, Minutes, Seconds), and i could have something similiar to the Increase buttons, right?

Comment: @F.Carvalho, i suggest yes

Comment: Thank you. I will be using this method for my project.